# Turning loader content into MovieClips in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, compiler-errors, loader

So here's a loader that works:

```
public var loaders:Array = new Array();
public var loaderClip:Array = new Array();
    function loadPersonmenu() {

        var person:Array = new Array();
        var url:Array = new Array();
        var cityUrl:Array = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < personNumber; i++) {
            loaders.push(new Loader());
            loaders[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);
            loaders[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, lightUp);
            person.push("person" + i + ".swf");  
            url.push(new URLRequest(person[i]));
            loaders[i].load(url[i]);
            loaders[i].x = ((i + 1) * margin) + (i * videoWidth);
            loaders[i].alpha = .5;
            container.addChild(loaders[i]);
            }
}
```

Everything is fantastic, super-duper, awesome. But when I add some lines to treat the loader content as a MovieClip (so I can apply the `stop()` function to it), the compiler explodes into an error-fiesta. All my pretty external SWFs vanish. The new lines are at the bottom with comments appended:

```
public var loaders:Array = new Array();
public var loaders:Array = new Array();
    function loadPersonmenu() {

        var person:Array = new Array();
        var url:Array = new Array();
        var cityUrl:Array = new Array();


        for (var i = 0; i < personNumber; i++) {
            loaders.push(new Loader());
            loaders[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorListener);
            loaders[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, lightUp);
            person.push("person" + i + ".swf");  
            url.push(new URLRequest(person[i]));
            loaders[i].load(url[i]);
            loaders[i].x = ((i + 1) * margin) + (i * videoWidth);
            loaders[i].alpha = .5;
            container.addChild(loaders[i]);
            loaderClip[i] = MovieClip(loaders[i].content); // Here is a new line
            loaderClip[i].stop(); // Here is another new line
        }
}
```

These are my errors:

> ```
> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>   at Menu/loadPersonmenu()
>   at Menu/fileCompleteListener()
>   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>   at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
> ```

The weird thing is, my function `fileCompleteListener()` doesn't even reference any of these Loader instances or SWFs, which is why I didn't include it in my code. This isn't a problem in the first conde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to be giving the loader chance to load anything, and so `loaders[i].content` is null.

Listen for the complete event before trying to access the loader content.  Because you are using multiple loaders you should also assign each loader an instance name using `i` so that you can use one generic complete listener and reference the loader name to assign the content to the correct index of `loaderClip`.

```
//in the loop
loaders[i].name = i;
loaders[i].contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleteHandler);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

//complete handler method
private function loadCompleteHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    var index:int = int(Loader(LoaderInfo(evt.target).loader).name);
    loaderClip[index] = LoaderInfo(evt.target).content;
}
```

Comment: But I am curious, why LoaderInfo(evt.target).content; instead of just evt.target.content?

Comment: I'm used to using an editor that complains at loose typing, aso it's become habit to cast everything I do.  `evt.target.content` would also work, as would `evt.target['content']`